# Who is George A Duckett? Can anyone just create a book out of our questions and answers?

Tags: discussion

I just noticed that there is a book titled "Computer Science Theory: Questions and Answers" by George A Duckett, which includes some of our questions and answers on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com

This is the link to the book https://books.google.com/books?id=VF1RDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT277&lpg=PT277&dq=tayfun+pay&source=bl&ots=TPfAbC0io1&sig=fNSudF5hPAi2VX-DzUqWWG_JNYI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjm0N75nIDaAhXoY98KHW-FCf84FBDoAQgnMAA#v=onepage&q=tayfun%20pay&f=false

Questions:

1) Who is George A Duckett?

2) Can anyone simply copy and paste our questions and answers from cstheory.stackexchange on a text editor and publish a book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) A person with no affiliation to Stack Exchange who published a large number of e-books compiled from Stack Exchange questions and answers. I don't think we should go any further than that on this topic.

2) User contributions to Stack Exchange are published under [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) (see the footer of this page), which allows anyone to

> Adapt — remix, transform, and build upon the material
>   for any purpose, even commercially.

So the answer is yes, provided proper attribution is given. I have not examined the book to find out if it gives proper attribution. But Jon Ericson wrote a [review](http://jericson.github.io/2016/02/19/duckett_review.html) of a similar book based on another site.

Comment: "1) A person with no affiliation to Stack Exchange who published a large number of e-books compiled from Stack Exchange questions and answers. I don't think we should go any further than that on this topic." Yeah.. It is probably a fictional name. Okay! Thank You